# C# Thread-safe Extension Method

Tags: c#, multithreading, extension-methods, dispatcher

I may be waaaay off, or else really close.  Either way, I'm currently SOL. :)

I want to be able to use an extension method to set properties on a class, but that class may (or may not) be updated on a non-UI thread, and derives from a class the enforces updates to be on the UI thread (which implements INotifyPropertyChanged, etc).

I have a class defined something like this:

```
public class ClassToUpdate : UIObservableItem
{
    private readonly Dispatcher mDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    private Boolean mPropertyToUpdate = false;

    public ClassToUpdate() : base()
    {
    }

    public Dispatcher Dispatcher
    {
        get { return mDispatcher; }
    }

    public Boolean PropertyToUpdate
    {
        get { return mPropertyToUpdate; }
        set { SetValue("PropertyToUpdate", ref mPropertyToUpdate, value; }
    }
}
```

I have an extension method class defined something like this:

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> SetMyProperty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sourceList,
                                                  Boolean newValue)
    {
       ClassToUpdate firstClass = sourceList.FirstOrDefault() as ClassToUpdate;

       if (firstClass.Dispatcher.Thread.ManagedThreadId != 
           System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
        {
            // WHAT GOES HERE?
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var classToUpdate in sourceList)
            {
               (classToUpdate as ClassToUpdate ).PropertyToUpdate = newValue;
               yield return classToUpdate;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, I'm looking for the "WHAT GOES HERE" in the extension method.

Thanks,
wTs

Comment: You have an enumerator called 'SetMyProperty' ? Maybe you should first decide what this function should actually do ?

Comment: @Henk: actually, I think it's some kind of fluent API : `sourceList.SetMyProperty(true).SetMyOtherProperty("hello").SetFoo(42)...`

Comment: Extension methods are nothing more than static methods can know how to 'decorate' values (this operation is done ENTIRELY at compile-time). Their thread-safety is in relation to what they do, and from what context. However, there is otherwise nothing special about them wrt. threading. I generally like to use SynchronizationContext's and dispatchers.

Comment: @Thomas: you are correct.  This is actually a much-simplified method to use as an example to represent a number of more complex methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> // WHAT GOES HERE?

```
mDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => sourceList.SetMyProperty(newValue)));
```

As a side note, if you need to check whether the current thread has access to the UI, you don't need to compare thread ids. You just need to call the `CheckAccess` method :

```
if (firstClass.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
{
    ...
}
```

For some reason, this methods is hidden in Intellisense... no idea why

---

UPDATE

OK, my answer wasn't totally accurate... you still need to `yield return` each item of the collection, and Invoke doesn't do it. Here's another version of your method :

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SetMyProperty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sourceList, bool newValue)
    where T : ClassToUpdate
{
    Action<T> setProperty = t => t.PropertyToUpdate = newValue;

    foreach(var t in sourceList)
    {
        if (t.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            action(t);
        }
        else
        {
            t.Dispatcher.Invoke(action, new object[] { t });
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I added a constaint on the generic type parameter, and I removed the casts (the way you were doing it, generics didn't bring any benefit)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is working.  For some reason, breakpoints and tracepoints aren't hit in the function after calling Invoke.  I would expect to hit a breakpoint at the first line of the function after Invoke is called.

Comment: Also, does the Invoke have the same effect as the other loop, which creates an IEnumerable via a yield return?  The object returned from the Invoke is null.

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to solve it using your example.  Oh, and I also had a constraint of my real class - I just didn't put it in the quick example above.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clean up a couple of small typos (and hopefully not add my own) in the above example, here is a final solution to the example.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> SetMyProperty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sourceList, 
    bool newValue) where T : ClassToUpdate
{
    Action<T> setProperty = t => t.PropertyToUpdate = newValue;

    foreach(var t in sourceList)
    {
        if (t.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            setProperty(t);
        }
        else
        {
            t.Dispatcher.Invoke(setProperty, new object[] { t });
        }

        yield return t;
    }
}
```